# Calculator using checkbox values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails.. so please help me figure it out.. thank u.. :)

I am trying to create a simple calculator

I am getting `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

**calculator_controller.rb**

```
      class CalculatorController < ApplicationController
                   def calculate
                        pasta = params [:pasta]
                        noodles = params [:noodles]
                        @result = pasta.to_i + noodles.to_i
                        redirect_to result_path
                   end
           end
```

**/views/page/calculator.html.erb**

```
             <%= form_tag({:controller => "calculator", :action => "calculate"}, :method => "post") do %>
                      <div>
                             <%= check_box_tag 'pasta', '100' %>MENU ITEM 1
                      </div>
                      <div>
                             <%= check_box_tag 'noodles', '200' %>MENU ITEM 2
                      </div>
                      <div>
                              <%= submit_tag('Submit', :disable_with => 'Submitting...')%> 
                      </div>
            <% end %>
```

**/views/calculator/result.html.erb**

```
    <div>
       <%= @result %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack?

Comment: do u mean this
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Wz2V5sRJHjMyWbV78S7DxFdUrYcbnjYHNp1Ef/FPqAQ=",
 "pasta"=>"100",
 "noodles"=>"200",
 "commit"=>"Submit"}

Comment: No,not that.I mean the Error Info.Page and line where the error is raised.

Comment: it has highlighted  pasta = params [:pasta]

Comment: Try to Post the Error stack.The error could be in any other controller.

Comment: sorry to sound way too much noob but what is a error stack and  where do i find it!!

Comment: did you mean content of development .log!!

Comment: Its ok leave it!I will try finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: Could you post your Calculate model?

Comment: it is blank.. i m not tring to use model for now..

Comment: all i am trying to accomplish for now is to add those numbers and show.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController
                   def calculate
                        pasta = params [:pasta]
                        noodles = params [:noodles]
                        @result = pasta.to_i + noodles.to_i
                        redirect_to result_path
                   end
           end
```

Here you are redirecting to the result_path. So the value in the @result is lost. So if you want to keep the value of @result, you can keep it in session or pass it by using params or use the flash or render the view
I am going to use render the view over here.

There is a space between `params` and `[:pasta]`. Thats why you are getting this error. remove the space, it will work for you.

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController
                       def calculate
                            pasta = params[:pasta]
                            noodles = params[:noodles]
                            @result = pasta.to_i + noodles.to_i
                            render 'result'
                       end
               end
```

In the view

```
<div>
       <%= @result %>
    </div>
```

Comment: wud it help if i post latest content refering to this error from development.log

Comment: can you share the error that you got with line number of the file?

Comment: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/controllers/calculator_controller.rb:3:in `calculate'

Comment: Modified my answer. This error is due to you have space between `params` and `[:YOUR-SYMBOL]`.